# force:inputField is not displaying String values in salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning, lds

I am facing a challenge, force:inputField contain string value is not displaying in   output , while when i use lightning:input it display value.

here is my code

component  code

```
<aura:component controller="ContactController">
    <aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" 
               default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact' }"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <div class="slds-p-around_xx-small" >
    <lightning:input fieldName="Name" value="{!v.contact.Name}"/>
    <force:inputField value="{!v.contact.Id}"/>       !---- this shows value
        <force:outputField value="{!v.contact.Name}"/>
        <force:inputField value="{!v.contact.Name}"/>   !---  this line doesnot give output value
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller Code

```
({
     doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getContact");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.contact", response.getReturnValue());
                console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            }
         });
         $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    }     
})
```

Apex code

```
public with sharing class ContactController {

     @AuraEnabled
    public static Contact getContact() {
        return [select Id, firstName from Contact Limit 1];
    }


}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Ashish Nigam the field Name is not writable so might not be present there. Try using FirstName instead of name field. As contact will have FirstName and LastName. Name might not be available for Input or output.

Try adding the controller to :

```
public class ContactController {
  @AuraEnabled
    public static Contact getContact() {
        return [select Id, FirstName,phone,Name from Contact Limit 1];
    }

}
```

and the tags in component as :

```
<force:inputField value="{!v.contact.FirstName}"/>
```

Comment: Hi, yes I tried the same with first Name and last name, but it won't . also if you check that lightning:input is shown the Name field information.

Comment: Also when I try to inspect in the debugger, it has shown the result perfectly, but no Output.